# Python regex substitute string in code file

Tags: python, regex

I try to use Python v3.12.0 regex to reformat **strings in a code source file** to resemble C++ raw string format.

#### Sample input file

F.i. the following code in file `myclassA.txt` (code is in a **C++-like dialect, please mind the special way of declaring multi-line strings**):

````cpp
class myClassA(myBaseClass) {

  docstring =  // End-of-line-comments possible
"
This is my class description docstring stored in a string variable inherited from
myBaseClass.
The content of this string, INCLUDING INDENTATION, MUST NOT be changed.
";

  // This variable is declared as string has a mismatched indentation:
string some_detailed_notes = "Some string like this is also possible.
  Also with
    some really
   strange indentation
  and `inline code`, ```code blocks``` $\\text{LaTeX}$ $$\\frac{1}{2}$$
:::{hint}
some admonitions
:::
and all kind of special characters such as:
\"
(...)
{...}
[...]
;.,
etc.

which MUST be preserved.";

  string some_other_string = "
    do NOT touch this, only docstring and some_detailed_notes
  ";
}
````

#### Expected output

In this code file, I want to **replace all unescaped* string delimiters `"`** - but **not** `\"` such that the string resembles C++ raw string format:

```cpp
docstring = R""""(
my string
)"""";
```

resp. for the full input example:

````cpp
class myClassA(myBaseClass) {

  docstring =  // End-of-line-comments possible
R""""(
This is my class description docstring stored in a string variable inherited from
myBaseClass.
The content of this string, INCLUDING INDENTATION, MUST NOT be changed.
)"""";

  // This variable is declared as string has a mismatched indentation:
string some_detailed_notes = R""""(Some string like this is also possible.
  Also with
    some really
   strange indentation
  and `inline code`, ```code blocks``` $\\text{LaTeX}$ $$\\frac{1}{2}$$
:::{hint}
some admonitions
:::
and all kind of special characters such as:
\"
(...)
{...}
[...]
;.,
etc.

which MUST be preserved.)"""";

  string some_other_string = "
    do NOT touch this, only docstring and some_detailed_notes
  ";
}
````

#### What I tried so far

I tried the following regex to enclose the string group in C++-raw-string delimiters, **but only for the first occurrences of strings `docstring` and `some_detailed_notes`**.

```py
import pathlib
import re

fp = pathlib.Path('myclassA.txt').resolve(True)
txt = fp.read_text(encoding='utf-8')

cpp_rawstr_start = 'R""""('
cpp_rawstr_end = ')""""'

txt_sub = re.sub(
    r'([ ]*(docstring|some_detailed_notes)\s*=[\s\t\n]*")(?:(?!")(?:\\.|[^\\]))*";',
    fr'{cpp_rawstr_start}\n\g<0>\n{cpp_rawstr_end}',
    txt,
    count=2,
    flags=re.DOTALL
)
```

But this results in:

```cpp
R""""(
  docstring =  // End-of-line-comments possible
"
This is my class description docstring stored in a string variable inherited from
myBaseClass.
The content of this string, INCLUDING INDENTATION, MUST NOT be changed.
";
)""""
```

which is of course not exactly what I wanted, furthermore `some_detailed_notes` **is not touched at all**.

##### Additional task

**Only if feasible and not too complicated**, I'd also like to include strings defined using enclosing parentheses:

```cpp
docstring = (
"
Enclosed in parentheses
"
);
```

to be converted to

```cpp
docstring =
R""""(
Enclosed in parentheses
)"""";
```

dropping the parentheses is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your regex is that you're capturing the entire definition string and then surrounding that with the raw string delimiters. But it also doesn't allow for comments to end of line or parentheses. You can use this regex instead:

```
(?<=\s)((?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)\s*=\s*\(?\s*(?://.*\n\s*)*)"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)+)"(\s*\)?\s*;)
```

This matches:

- `(?<=\s)` : lookbehind for whitespace
- `(` : start of capture group 1
- `(?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)` : either `docstring` or `some_detailed_notes`
- `\s*=\s*\(?\s*` : whitespace, an `=` and an optional `(`
- `(?://.*\n\s*)*` : 0 or more comments to end of line
- `)` : end of capture group 1
- `"` : a `"`
- `((?:[^"\\]|\\.)+)` : some number of either: a character which is not a `"` or a `\`; or any character preceded by a `\`, all captured in group 2
- `"` : a `"`
- `(\s*\)?\s*;)` : whitespace, an optional `)` and a `;`, all captured in group 3

You can then replace that with `\1R""""(\2)""""\3` which encloses the previously quoted string inside `R""""` and `""""`.

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2CHbKE/1)

In python

````py
txt = '''class myClassA(myBaseClass) {

  docstring =  // End-of-line-comments possible
"
This is my class description docstring stored in a string variable inherited from
myBaseClass.
The content of this string, INCLUDING INDENTATION, MUST NOT be changed.
";

docstring = (
"
Enclosed in parentheses
"
);

  // This variable is declared as string has a mismatched indentation:
string some_detailed_notes = "Some string like this is also possible.
  Also with
    some really
   strange indentation
  and `inline code`, ```code blocks``` $\\text{LaTeX}$ $$\\frac{1}{2}$$
:::{hint}
some admonitions
:::
and all kind of special characters such as:
\\"
(...)
{...}
[...]
;.,
etc.

which MUST be preserved.";

  string some_other_string = "
    do NOT touch this, only docstring and some_detailed_notes
  ";
}
'''
 print(re.sub(r'(?<=\s)((?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)\s*=\s*\(?\s*(?://.*\n\s*)*)"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)+)"(\s*\)?\s*;)', r'\1R""""(\2)""""\3', txt))
````

Output:

````
class myClassA(myBaseClass) {

  docstring =  // End-of-line-comments possible
R""""(
This is my class description docstring stored in a string variable inherited from
myBaseClass.
The content of this string, INCLUDING INDENTATION, MUST NOT be changed.
)"""";

docstring = (
R""""(
Enclosed in parentheses
)""""
);

  // This variable is declared as string has a mismatched indentation:
string some_detailed_notes = R""""(Some string like this is also possible.
  Also with
    some really
   strange indentation
  and `inline code`, ```code blocks``` $\text{LaTeX}$ $$\frac{1}{2}$$
:::{hint}
some admonitions
:::
and all kind of special characters such as:
\"
(...)
{...}
[...]
;.,
etc.

which MUST be preserved.)"""";

  string some_other_string = "
    do NOT touch this, only docstring and some_detailed_notes
  ";
}
````

Comment: And considering execution speed: I want to use this on a ~1000 files but only on strings `docstring` and `some_detailed_notes`. Should I split this into two separate regexes or keep a single regex searching for both?

Comment: That's awesome, thanks alot. And great explanation. I just fixed the C++ raw string literal delimiters. In a separate answer I extended your solution to also replace the enclosing parentheses.

Comment: @JE_Muc I don't think it would be any faster to use two regexes, there's only the one branch in this one on the two strings and it would get resolved pretty quickly. Sorry I didn't notice the `()` in the delimiters, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of Nick (thanks!) I was able to also reformat strings enclosed in parentheses, using the following regex:

```py
cpp_rawstr_start = 'R""""('
cpp_rawstr_end = ')""""'
txt_sub = re.sub(
    (
        r'(?<=\s)'  # Group 1
        r'((?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)\s*=\s*(?://.*\n\s*)*)'  # Group 2
        r'("|\(\s*")((?:[^"\\]|\\.)+)'  # Group 3: string to enclose
        r'("|"\s*\))'  # Group 4
        r'(\s*;)'  # Group 5
    ),
    fr'\1{cpp_rawstr_start}\3{cpp_rawstr_end}\5',
    txt,
)
```

Quoting Nick for most of the explanations:

- `(?<=\s)` : lookbehind for whitespace
- `(` : start of capture group 1
- `(?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)` : either `docstring` or `some_detailed_notes`
- `\s*=\s*` : optional  whitespaces around `=`
- `(?://.*\n\s*)*` : 0 or more comments to end of line
- `)` : end of capture group 1
- `("|\(\s*")` : group 2 (**to be replaced by start delimiter**): Either a `"` or `( "` with 0-x whitespaces between the `(` and the `"`
- `((?:[^"\\]|\\.)+)` : some number of either: a character which is not a `"` or a `\`; or any character preceded by a `\`, all captured in group 3 - **the actual string**
- `("|"\s*\))` : Group 3: A closing `"` or `" )` with optional whitespaces between - **to be replaced by end delimiter**
- `(\s*;)` : Group5: optional whitespace and a `;`

which leads to the following output, correctly replacing parentheses:

````cpp
class myClassA(myBaseClass) {

  docstring =  // End-of-line-comments possible
R""""(
This is my class description docstring stored in a string variable inherited from
myBaseClass.
The content of this string, INCLUDING INDENTATION, MUST NOT be changed.
)"""";

docstring = R""""(
Enclosed in parentheses
)"""";

  // This variable is declared as string has a mismatched indentation:
string some_detailed_notes = R""""(Some string like this is also possible.
  Also with
    some really
   strange indentation
  and `inline code`, ```code blocks``` $\text{LaTeX}$ $$\frac{1}{2}$$
:::{hint}
some admonitions
:::
and all kind of special characters such as:
\"
(...)
{...}
[...]
;.,
etc.

which MUST be preserved.)"""";

  string some_other_string = "
    do NOT touch this, only docstring and some_detailed_notes
  ";
}
````

Please let me know, if you see any problematic parts or if anything can be improved.