# Python regex replace quotation marks

Tags: python, regex

Based on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77846735/6345518), I realized that many of my strings are in fact concatenated strings, which makes replacing quotation marks with C++ raw string literal delimiters even harder.

F.i. I'd like to substitute the quotation marks in this text:

```
text = r'''
docstring = "mystr";

docstring = "some \"subs" + some_str + "next";

docstring = (
  some_str + "cde" + some_str + "efg" + another_str + "ghi"
);
'''
```

to this

```
target_text = r'''
docstring = R""""(mystr)"""";

docstring = R""""(some \"subs)"""" + some_str + R""""(next)"""";

docstring =
  some_str + R""""(cde)"""" + some_str + R""""(efg)"""" + another_str + R""""(ghi)"""";
'''
```

with the parentheses around the last concatenation being dropped and preserving special characters like the escaped `\"`.

My current approach is the following regex

```
import re
re.sub(
    r'(?<=[\s])((?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)\s*=\s*(?://.*\n\s*)*)(("|\(\s*")((?:[^"\\]|\\.)+)("|"\s*\)))([\+_a-z ]*)(\s*;)',
    fr'\1{cpp_rawstr_start}\3{cpp_rawstr_end}\5'
    text
)
```

but of course this won't work due to two reasons:

- my regex doesn't match the groups unless there is only one concatenation
- group order/numbering changes depending on the string to analyze. Honestly: Absolutely no idea how to deal with this...

I also tried this [regex on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2IGG9X/1) but can't make it work.

Comment: `\"` is going to be turned into just `"` in the string, unless you make it a raw string or escape the backslash.

Comment: This is not easy to do with regular expressions, they're not good at detecting inside vs. outside context. Use a parser library.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the hint. I escaped the text string. Also thanks for the advice. Do you have any library in mind? Or what about simply iterating over the lines to find the `docstring` variable and then parse the following lines until `";` by hand?

Comment: @Barmar is right.  This would be way easier to handle using a simple `for c in str:` loop, going character by character, tracking the inside/outside state yourself.

Comment: If you need this to work for any text that is a valid Python string (or some language like it), you should follow the advice and find a parser library - this is not the place for recommendations, but there are plenty out there. If your source texts are more limited and really just contain double quotes or escaped double quotes, you could break up the text using regex, perform a clever replacement separately with a basic loop and then reassemble the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a two-stage approach to this using `re.sub` with a replacer function. The regex passed to `re.sub` matches the `docstring =`  and rest of string in separate groups, then the replacer function splits the rest on `+` and replaces strings with the appropriately escaped version:

```py
def replacer(m):
    res = m[1]
    strings = re.split(r'(\s*\+\s*)(?=(?:[^"]*"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"[^"]*)*$)', m[3])
    for i, s in enumerate(strings):
        if i % 2 or not s.startswith('"'):
            res = res + s
        else:
            res = res + 'R""""(' + s.strip()[1:-1] + ')""""'
    return res + ';'

target_text = re.sub(r'((?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)\s*=\s*)(\(\s*)?((?:"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"|[^;])+)(?(2)\s*\)|)\s*;', replacer, text)
```

For this input:

```
docstring = "mystr()" + abc(some_args) + "other \";str";

docstring = "mystr";

docstring = "some \"subs" + some_str + "next";

docstring = (
  some_str + "cde" + some_str + "efg" + another_str + "ghi"
);
'''
```

this produces:

```
docstring = R""""(mystr())"""" + abc(some_args) + R""""(other \";str)"""";

docstring = R""""(mystr)"""";

docstring = R""""(some \"subs)"""" + some_str + R""""(next)"""";

docstring = some_str + R""""(cde)"""" + some_str + R""""(efg)"""" + another_str + R""""(ghi)"""";
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working with almost all special characters. Only exception: The variables to concatenate to the string have a `()` or `( some_args)`, f.i. `docstring = "mystr()" + abc(some_args) + "other \";str";`, in other words are function calls. I tried dropping the closing parentheses from the regex 2nd capt. group: `ptrn = re.compile(r'((?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)\s*=\s*)(?:\(\s*)?((?:"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"|[^;])+)(?:\s*\))?\s*;')`. This works, but now the closing parentheses of the last test string are included in the output.

Comment: Ok, I guess I managed it by making the **2nd group non-greedy**: ptrn = re.compile(r'((?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)\s*=\s*)(?:\(\s*)?((?:"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"|[^;])+?)(?:\s*\))?\s*;')

Comment: @JE_Muc we can work around that by using a conditional group to force the trailing `)` to match when an opening `(` is found. See my edit (note the replacer function has also changed). Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/0zCkzD/1). This should be more robust than using a non-greedy capture.

Comment: Ah yeah, that sounds like a good idea, thanks! I'll give it a try right away.

Comment: Now the closing `;` will be on a separate line, if there are parentheses around the string. Again I worked around this using a non-greedy 2nd group: `re.compile(
    r'((?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)\s*=\s*)(\(\s*)?((?:"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"|[^;])+?)(?(2)\s*\)|)\s*;'
)`. Is there a better option for this case?

Comment: @JE_Muc that doesn't happen in the sample data in my answer, do you have an example string which demonstrates it?

Answer (score 1):

Not fully tested but should get you started:

```
text = r'''
docstring = "mystr";

docstring = "some \"subs" + some_str + "next";

test = "some other weirdo text";

test12 = 123;

docstring = (
  some_str + "cde" + some_str + "efg" + another_str + "ghi"
);
'''

quote = False
offset = 0
result = []

for idx, char in enumerate(text):
    if char == '"' and text[idx - 1] != '\\':
        if not quote:
            result.append(text[offset:idx] + 'R""""(')
        else:
            result.append(text[offset:idx] + ')""""')

        quote = not quote
        offset = idx+1

# chars left?
if (offset < idx):
    result.append(text[offset:idx])

print("".join(result))
```

The idea is to look for unescaped quotes, splice the original string, add the appropriate expressions and glue them together afterwards.

---

This results in

```
docstring = R""""(mystr)"""";

docstring = R""""(some \"subs)"""" + some_str + R""""(next)"""";

test = R""""(some other weirdo text)"""";

test12 = 123;

docstring = (
  some_str + R""""(cde)"""" + some_str + R""""(efg)"""" + another_str + R""""(ghi)""""
);
```

---

If you really only want to alter lines that start with `docstring|some_detailed_notes`, then you have to dig deeper into your bag of tricks, use a regular expression in the first place and move the above logic in a replacer function like so:

```
import regex as re

# variables
pattern = re.compile(r"""
    ^
    (?:docstring|some_detailed_notes)\s+=\s+
    (?(?=").+|(\(([^()]|(?R))*\));)
    """, re.M | re.X)

def replacer(match):
    # algorithm
    quote = False
    offset = 0
    result = []
    string = match.group(0)

    for idx, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == '"' and string[idx - 1] != '\\':
            if not quote:
                result.append(string[offset:idx] + 'R""""(')
            else:
                result.append(string[offset:idx] + ')""""')

            quote = not quote
            offset = idx+1

    # chars left?
    if (offset <= idx):
        result.append(string[offset:idx+1])

    return "".join(result)

text = pattern.sub(replacer, text)
print(text)
```

---

This uses a recursive approach for the `docstring = (...)` construct (you might want to work on that bit) and would produce for the aforementioned text:

```
docstring = R""""(mystr)"""";

docstring = R""""(some \"subs)"""" + some_str + R""""(next)"""";

test = "some other weirdo text";

test12 = 123;

docstring = (
  some_str + R""""(cde)"""" + some_str + R""""(efg)"""" + another_str + R""""(ghi)""""
);
```

As you see, lines that do have quotes but do not start with `docstring` were left untouched. See a demo for the regex expression on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jurayn/1) and be sure to use `regex` instead of `re` as the former supports recursion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unluckily I can't make it work in Python 3.12. When compiling the pattern, I get the error `re.error: bad character in group name '?="' at position 59 (line 4, column 8)`. Also the regex101 seems to be set to PECRE2 and not Python.

Comment: Have you noticed the `regex` import statement?

Comment: Do you mean `import regex as re`? If yes: Sure, else I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @JE_Muc: Mal kurz auf deutsch. Du brauchst das `regex` Modul (`pip install regex`), weil nur das den regulären Ausdruck unterstützt. Und dann den Quelltext kopieren und laufen lassen.